# Python-GI's WebKit signal pointer writing

Tags: python, pygtk, webkitgtk

I'm using PyWebKitGTK on pygobject to embed a WebView into my application. I need to call some python methods from JS code, so I try to use the [`script-prompt` signal](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/WebKit-3.0/classes/WebView.html#WebKit.WebView.signals.script_prompt).

How do I assign the  the `text` parameter? In C/++, it would be a pointer, so I could write data there (I suppose? Didn't have much C experience), but here it is `object`:

> **text** (`object`) – To be filled with the return value or None if the dialog was cancelled.

Comment: I believe you are misunderstanding the purpose of the signal. It is emitted when some JavaScript uses the prompt function to get input from the user. Webkit will display a dialog box with a message and an input field, where the user is supposed to place its answer to the message (like *"Please enter your email:"*). When the user clicks "OK", the content of the input field is placed into the `text` parameter and the signal is emitted.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp

Comment: @Cilyan Nope, the signal gets called _before_ the dialog is shown, so we can misuse it :) If we `return True`, the dialog won't be shown to user and the `text` will be used as a return value. Consider this: https://gist.github.com/iamale/b91e7f06056259841d3f